# MIPS Decompiler

Tags: mips, decompiler

I'm looking for a decompiler capable of transforming MIPS machine code into C code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might find [this](http://www.backerstreet.com/rec/rec.htm) to be useful.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have a MIPS object file or executable file, you can use objdump from the free [Code Sourcery Gnu toolchain](http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/mips).

`mips-linux-gnu-objdump -d foo.o > foo.S`

Answer (score 4):

There is [JEB](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/jeb2/mips), which now supports decompilation of MIPS 32-bit code. The output (pseudo-C) is interactive and can be refactored/modified. There is a free demo.